# why do i wrong redirect when accessing prometheus ussing nginx?

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, prometheus

I need some help setting up Prometheus and Nginx.
My idea is to have a docker-compose file that contains Prometheus and Nginx. Users will have to be rooted from nginx to reach Prometheus.

Now this is only part of my docker-compose file:

```
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
```

and this is the relevant part of the nginx.conf file:

```
  server {
    listen 80;
    location /prometheus/ {
      proxy_pass http://prometheus:9090/;
    }
  }
```

This solution works ok but it has the following problem. When I would access
**http://localhost/prometheus/** I'm redirected to **http://localhost/graph** which is not an existing page. I should be redirected to:
**http://localhost/prometheus/** -> **http://localhost/prometheus/graph**.
The other redirects work. It looks to me that Prometheus does not know it's base URL.

If possible please provide some config that would work.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Prometheus that its root location is `/prometheus/` and not `/` (the default). There is [a startup argument](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/command-line/prometheus/) for that: `--web.route-prefix`. So with docker-compose it'll be something like this:

```yaml
services:
  prometheus:
    # override default CMD for this container
    command:
    - --web.route-prefix=/prometheus/
    # these flags are default for the prom/prometheus image
    # you gonna need them because of the override
    - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    - --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus
    - --web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries
    - --web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles
```

Or you might want to use `--web.external-url=https://example.com/prometheus/` instead. See this doc for more info https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/command-line/prometheus/.